# Como asignar valor a input con vuejs mediante peticion axios?

Tags: php, javascript, vue.js, axios

Estoy realizando la peticion con axios, y una vez recibido los datos quiero insertarlos en el input, pero no lo asigna, no se por que, aqui el codigo:

vista:

```
<div id="contenedor">
        <h1>Welcome to admin</h1>
        <form>
            <label>User:</label>
            <input type="text" name="user" v-model = "user">
            <label>Pass:</label>
            <input type="text" name="pass" v-model = "pass">
        </form>
        <button @click="login">Login</button>
</div>
```

vuejs:

```
contenedor  = new Vue ({
el: '#contenedor',
data: {
    user: '',
    pass: '',
},
methods: {
    login: function() {
        axios.post('./Views/prueba.php',{'user':this.user}).then(function(response){
          this.pass = response.data; //aqui es donde deberia asignarle el valor al input pass, pero no lo hace
          console.log(response.data); // si imprime el valor por consola
        },function(response) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    )},
}})
```

archivo php:

```
<?php

$user = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

echo json_encode($user["user"]);

?>
```

gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Recomendacion.

Siempre que utilizes data en un componente Vuejs debes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
data: {
  return {
     user: '',
     pass: '',
    }
},
```

Espero y eso arregle tu error,  un saludo :))

Answer (score 0):

También tu sugiero que cuando hagas una petición a axios coloca la direccion correctamente.

Si es local coloca la dirección con su puerto, por ejemplo: 
**http://localhost:4000/**

```js
 login: function() {
        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/Views/prueba.php',{'user':this.user}).then(function(response){
          this.pass = response.data; //aqui es donde deberia asignarle el valor al input pass, pero no lo hace
          console.log(response.data); // si imprime el valor por consola
        },function(response) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    )},
```